# Create a multiple choice list of value in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I am using ArcGIS Pro desktop.

I have a classic layer stored in a geodatabase. For one of the field of this layer, I would like my users to be able to select multiple values from a list of values.

As an example: User 1 select Attribute A + Attribute B + Attribute C from a prompt list. When validate it's setup as "A;B;C" within the database.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of two approaches:

"Pick lists" on a field can be applied using [Domains](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/an-overview-of-attribute-domains.htm), this filters what a user can enter and are a great way of quality controlling input. Domains do not allow multiple selection as their input, its just one value from a list that can be selected. If you really do just have A, B, C as your options then you could create a Domain with the following combinations:

A

B

C

AB

AC

BC

ABC

Any more and it becomes untenable to maintain and use.

An alternative approach is create a model\python scripting tool where the interface allows multiple selections from a list (that's easy to set up) and then that does a field calculate and writes the user chosen list **to the selected row**. So in this scenario the user goes selects the feature on the map, ensures they have a single feature selected, then run the custom geoprocessing tool.

I would also question the value of writing A;B;C as a value to a feature as you are clearly trying to represent a 1:Many relationship and the approach you are suggesting is not best practise. A related table would be best, so the featureclass for feature X will have 3 rows in its related table if you wanted to store A,B and C against it. Again you need only search the help file on related tables to find out more.

Comment: Thank you for this solid answer. I do have more than 3 values to chose. Therefore it's one of the reason I do not want to use a list with n possibilities (which was the practise of my predecessor). 

Writting A;B;C in a single value let you make selections and analysis quite easely. 

I do agrea a more solid practise would be to create n columns one for each possible value and write yes/no for each one of thoses values. This works for some case, but let say I have a road and would like to concatenate every cities crossed by this road in a single field. CityA;CityB;CityC will be better